# When to use debug and release Android builds

Tags: android, google-play, crashlytics

I'm working on test Android app and can build it as 'release' and 'debug',

Development takes place on laptops with Android Studio, 
Testing will be based on Crashlytics,
Production will be on GPlay.

Please advice what (and why) should I chose between 'release' and 'debug' for each environment?

Comment: debug when you are debugging, release when you are releasing

Answer (score 0):

Your Android app will execute in debug mode in your development environment, such as while installing an app from Eclipse or Android Studio IDEs and it will execute in release mode when installing from Google Play. In release mode any debug logging, StrictMode and the debugging option must be disabled.

Comment: Ok, but what about testing stage, Crashlytics in my case, should it be debug or release?

Comment: you can use different android:versionString for debug and release mode and then disable crash reporting from the Crashlytics web dashboard for the debug version.

Comment: so your advice is to upload debug build to Crashlytics?

Comment: Suppose if you want to provide the build to someone for testing then you have to upload debug build in crashlytics for beta testing.

Comment: And what benefits debug builds give for qa team when they're using Crashlytics? In previous answer  @Bakhrom Rakhmonov advised to use release build

Comment: QA team can get updated build whenever you update the build and invited peoples can get updates. even they can provide feedback to. @Bakhrom Rakhmonov is right you should use builds according to your requirements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161209/discussion-between-aj-27-and--).

Answer (score 0):

Use 'release' build to publish your app to GooglePlay. The time it takes to execute the build will be bit longer than if you use the 'debug' build.
Use 'debug' to run your app locally and test your app.

Also, the release build has ProGuard (code shrinking) for detecting and removing unused code from your app.

Comment: I think you should use release build with proguard configuration for Crashlytics [crashlytics dex-proguard conf](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html)

Comment: thanks, so I should use 'debug' only when I work on my laptop, correct?

Comment: Yes! use debug only in run app locally. to debug app using android debugger, catlog, etc.